# Badge count not displaying in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using [this](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-forms-tab-badge) plugin for display badge count on tab. But some how it's not displaying. I think the problem with Naxam.Bottombar.plugin is used for display tabbar at the bottom in android. Because If I am using default TabbedPage then it works fine. How can I solve this?

I have followed all steps described in the badge plugin.

Code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Graysons.Views.MenuPage" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Graysons.Customs"
         xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:Graysons.Controls"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Graysons.ViewModels"  
         xmlns:convertors="clr-namespace:Graysons.Convertors"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"
         xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:Graysons.StringResources"  
         xmlns:plugin="clr-namespace:Plugin.Badge.Abstractions;assembly=Plugin.Badge.Abstractions" 
         Title="Menus" Icon="ic_menus.png" plugin:TabBadge.BadgeText="1" plugin:TabBadge.BadgeColor="Red" plugin:TabBadge.BadgePosition="PositionBottomRight" plugin:TabBadge.BadgeMargin="15"
         Style="{StaticResource CustomTopBar}">
..............
</ContentPage>
```

Also Added Line for rendering badge count in `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the whole page ?

Comment: Means code of this page?

Comment: Show the custom renderer please

Comment: Yes the coce for this page where you have made your tabs

Comment: I am using https://github.com/NAXAM/bottomtabbedpage-xamarin-forms this plugin.

Comment: @G.hakim, So how can I solve this?

Comment: I need to see your menupage and your Custom Rendrer in Android

Comment: @G.hakim, Sure I will share with you. But the problem is I am using third party plugin and that is not working. Default tabbed page is works fine.

Comment: Does it give you any compile time error? And I hope you know the package you are using only works for android so you don't need ios?

Comment: Yes, I know and It doesn't give any compilation Error. FYI I am testing this on Android and I am having Issue with that.

Comment: for showing Badge you not need to use third party plugins. Just type Tab.Badge=YourValue in your custom renderer.

Comment: But I am using BottomNavigationBar for custom Renderer. And Can't find property badge.

Comment: Did you solve this?  I'm trying to solve for bottom nav bar as well. :(

Comment: No. I have just changed plugin.

Answer (score 2):

the following renderer to be added Platform specific folders, not in the main project AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(BadgedTabbedPageRenderer))]
```

*for eg: for iOS.*

Sample.iOS/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs

use this header

```
using Plugin.Badge.iOS;
```

then use the renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(BadgedTabbedPageRenderer))]
```

*for Android.*

Sample.Android/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs

use this header

```
using Plugin.Badge.Droid;
```

then use the renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(BadgedTabbedPageRenderer))]
```